# Hide a folder to prevent user access

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains data and I want to hide just this folder.
I have managed to do this by locking, but then lose access to the data.
The data needs to be available for program / application access but not for a user to open change or delete.
I hope i have explained this correctly.

Comment: What is "hide" - make inaccessible ?

Comment: Did you mean "lose"?

Comment: i want to hide the folder from view but have the contents accessible

Comment: Would a locked folder serve your interests?

Comment: If a locked folder is what I need, but the data inside must remain accessible when the folder is locked.

Comment: This is not a PS issue. It is a file-system setting on the file or folder object. Just set object attributes to hidden in Windows Explorer using a right click. Just because an object is marked as hidden, anyone can still get to it by removing the attribute directly or changing a setting in Windows Explorer view. You need to set objects ACL (access control list) to limit who can interact with it. Yet, if the user is Admin and can elevate to Admin on the box, the can just change that as well.

Comment: You should learn a little bit about NTFS permissions, the whole point of which are to prevent unauthorized user access.

Comment: The brief i required ( perhaps not explained that well in the first place. I want to hide the folder so the user cant see it ( solves all the problems ) this is to prevent the OOP's moment, the well it wasn't me and I never touched that folder why would I. it happens my way it cant happen if you cant see it. if you have a mind to go searching for stuff  then yes you will find it.

Comment: @Alan-53, try explaining it more clearly in the original question, not in comments. Edit your question so people can understand what it is you *exactly* want. You run the risk of the question being closed otherwise.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I thought I would place this here as my question has been answered by another person away from Stack Exchange.
I asked if he minded, his comment was give knowledge to all even if they don't understand it ) He must be talking about me.

@echo off
title Lock Data Folder
set _folder="C:\Users???????????????\This Folder" ( enter the full path to the Folder )

dir /a:h %_folder%>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 goto PASS1

dir /a:s %_folder%>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 goto PASS1

:CONFIRM
echo Do you want to lock the Private Folder?! [Y/N]
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto end
if %cho%==N goto end
echo Error! Wrong answer, please type [Y/N]
goto CONFIRM

:LOCK
attrib +h +s %_folder%
echo The folder sucsessfully locked...
pause
goto end

:PASS1
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter PIN!' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if NOT "%password%"=="Password Here" goto FAIL1
attrib -s -h %_folder%
goto EXP

:PASS2
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Masukkan PIN!' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if NOT "%password%"=="Password Here" goto FAIL2
attrib -s -h %_folder%
goto EXP

:PASS3
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Masukkan PIN!' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if NOT "%password%"=="Password Here" goto FAIL3
attrib -s -h %_folder%

:EXP
echo Folder successfully unlocked, do you want to look it? [Y/N]
set/p "tuju=>"
if %tuju%==Y goto BUKA
if %tuju%==y goto BUKA
if %tuju%==n goto end
if %tuju%==N goto end
echo Error! Wrong choice, When [Y/N]
goto EXP

:BUKA
echo Go to folder...
pause
start explorer %_folder%
goto end

:FAIL1
echo Wrong PIN!
echo Try again, 2 remaining
goto PASS2

:FAIL2
echo Wrong PIN!
echo Try again! 1 remaining
goto PASS3

:FAIL3
echo Wrong PIN!
echo Device will reboot!

:PIL
set/p "rst=Automatic Restart? [Y/N]"
if %rst%==Y goto RST
if %rst%==y goto RST
if %rst%==N goto MNL
if %rst%==n goto MNL
echo Error! wrong choice, pleas type [Y/N]
goto PIL

:end

Comment: This script just appears to set some NTFS attributes on the folder, which does not prevent access. There is is also a lot of pointless folderol in the script.

Comment: What do i know, I run the script it hides the folder from the user but the applications still have access to the data. if you can improve on this please be my guest, i would be very greatfull.